# What's the equivalent of assert.rejects in TypeScript?

Tags: node.js, typescript, assert

In node js we use `assert.rejects` to assert an error caused by async function. I found the `rejects` method was missing in TypeScript, how to assert async errors in TypeScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think using this function will solve your issue:

```
import * as assert from 'assert';
async function assertThrowsAsync(fn, regExp) {
    let f = () => {};
    try {
        await fn();
    } catch(e) {
        f = () => {throw e};
    } finally {
        assert.throws(f, regExp);
    }
}
```

And use it in your tests:

```
await assertThrowsAsync(async () => async_function_call_here(), /Error/);
```

Comment: Wow, it's a very clever way! But why isn't it builtin?

Comment: No idea but it should have been. My guess is that async/await functionalities will eventually be added to all the major modules but it will take some time.

Answer (score 0):

Neither JavaScript nor TypeScript offer their own `assert` functionality. If you search for "JavaScript assert" or similar (remember TypeScript is JavaScript plus static types and one or two other small things), you'll find various libraries to do it that you can choose among.

Answer (score 0):

[@MrfksIV's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55019472/769900) is excellent, but it's tedious to write that helper function and reference it always.

To assert async errors seems we can do it in this way, too:

```
try {
  await someOperation();
  assert(false, 'should not reach here');
} catch (ex) {
  assert(/Your Expected Error/.test(ex.message))
}
```